# How to run Hibernate's JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor Static Metamodel Generator on Scala entities

Tags: hibernate, scala, jpa-2.0

I'm able to run Hibernate's jpamodelgen on java-based JPA-entites having this in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

But this fails for entities written in Scala, of course. I've tried to "manually" generate the metamodel using the maven-processor-plugin having my pom.xml look like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <processors>
                    <!-- list of processors to use -->
                    <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                </processors>
                <!-- source output directory -->
                <outputDirectory>target/metamodel</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>target/metamodel</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But nothing happens.

Anybody has successfully generated the JPA metamodel from JPA entities written in Scala?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think this is possible as the metamodel generator runs within javac as pluggable annotation processor (http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=269), i.e. on the Java source.

Javac, however, won't understand your scala source and scalac (to my knowledge) doesn't and cannot support JSR 269 interface.